# Validate/Match JSON field for number and not string in the input request in Wiremock

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I am trying to validate a particular json field `amount` in the request to have number and not string

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/charges",
    "bodyPatterns" : [
      {"matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.amount =~ /^[0-9]*$/i)]"}
    ]
}
```

Now request1 and request2 are working fine and request3 fails. But I expect request2 to fail as well because it is a string and not number as it is in double quotes.

Request 1,

```
{
    "amount": 123,
}
```

Request 2,

```
{
    "amount": "123",
}
```

Request 3,

```
{
    "amount": "a123",
}
```

Is this possible?. I see in wiremock docs

```
    Since WireMock’s matching operators all work on strings, 
the value selected by the JSONPath expression will be coerced to a string before the match is evaluated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround.

As per the regex you have given, I see that the `amount` field cannot have negative values.

So in the matchesJsonPath, do a dummy check that the value is greater than or equal to zero. This will make sure that the value 123 will work but "123" will throw an error

You wouldn't even need to use the regex anymore.

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPath": "/charges",
    "bodyPatterns" : [
      {"matchesJsonPath" : "$[?(@.amount >= 0)]"}
    ]
}
```